# ColdFusion Admin Login and Password recovery

Tags: security, coldfusion

I recently took over the development of a CF site and am having some trouble obtaining the login and password to the Admin for CF.  I was hoping another StackOverflower may haave some insight on obtaining access.  We have access to the FTP and any other hosting related details.  Any helpful insight will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 13):

Open up the `password.properties` file which lies in `<coldfusion install directory>\lib`

You can see some encrypted string like

```
password=5BAA61E4C9B93F3F0682250B6CF8331B7EE68FD8
encrypted=true
```

Change it to clear text with `encrypted=false`

```
password=newPassword
encrypted=false
```

After that you can log in using `newPassword` and reset to a proper password in the CF Administrator.

Comment: This worked great in ColdFusion 9. I have the Enterprise version installed, so I thought sharing the full path to the password.properties might be helpful to someone in the future:  
`C:\JRun4\servers\[YourCFInstance]\cfusion.ear\cfusion.war\WEB-INF\cfusion\lib\password.properties`

Answer (score 3):

http://coldfusion8.blogspot.com/2008/08/what-if-you-forget-coldfusion-admin.html

I believe this also works for 6, 7,m and 9.

Answer (score 1):

Building on what Ben said Simon  Whatley has a great article outlining several different ways to accomplish this: http://www.simonwhatley.co.uk/resetting-a-lost-coldfusion-password really good stuff.

Comment: Upvoted because the article immediately tells you how to reset the password in ColdFusion 5.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Coldfusion on a Mac or Linux all you need to do is:

- On the terminal go to the bin directory of Coldfusion application
- There is a password reset script: passwordreset.sh
- running the script will ask you for a new password
- Stop and Restart Coldfusion

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest using the admin API to see if you could reset the password or even make a .car backup of the server settings in the event of a re-install.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=basiconfig_37.html

Answer (score 0):

For earlier versions, you can change a registry key, see details here : http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=3731