# Coldfusion 11 (Multi-instance) - Administrator password reset not working

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, forgot-password

I'm trying to reset the CFAdmin password on a CF11 Enterprise server that has [multiple CF instances running on the same server](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/configuring-administering/using-multiple-server-instances.html).  The admin password on one of the instances is unknown, so we're trying to recover/change to a known password.

1. I've tried using the [passwordreset.bat provided by Adobe](http://coldfusion-tip.blogspot.com/2014/02/reset-coldfusion-admin-password.html), but after restarting the instance with lost admin password, that didn't  work.
2. I also tried [disabling the password all together to access the admin console per adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/forgotten-password-cannot-log-coldfusion.html).  This gets me into the admin console temporarily, but I'm not able to actually *change* the password since I don't know the old password.  Leaving the old PW blank, fails too.  This is not a viable long-term option, we must have a password.
3. I even tried [editing the password.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833645/coldfusion-admin-login-and-password-recovery) file to type a password and set encryption=false, but that didn't work either.

I think I've exhausted all the standard ways to reset the password to no avail.  Is there something else that I should do because it's a multi-instance setup?  Is there some way to point it to the specific instance I want to change?

Comment: You should reach out to cf.install@adobe.com for help with this.

Comment: With option 3. It isn't clear from the description whether you stopped the application server, then edited password.properties and then restarted the server. I know this might seem a little obvious, but I just want to make sure? You need to stop, edit & start.